# Menu item “Interrupt Evaluation…” missing in V10

Tags: front-end, evaluation, version-10

The menu item “Interrupt Evaluation…” seems to have disappeared in Mathematica 10 on OS X.

Well, this is a bummer.

I personally use *Mathematica* for very long calculations, and I was using this function frequently to “pause” a calculation just the time to do another CPU-intensive task.

Any chance this can reappear in an update?

Comment: alt + , still works on v10 win 7

Comment: The documentation claims it is still available even though it's no longer there. And the shortcut given `Cmnd + ,` doesn't work either; that combination of keys brings up the Preferences dialog. A serious problem.

Comment: I find that the easiest way doing calculations alongside a long running calculation is to open a new notebook, and use Evaluation / Notebook's Kernel to attach the new notebook to an alternate kernel. You set up alternate kernels by using Evaluation / Kernel Configuration Options.

Comment: Maybe you can instead turn on `Evaluation > Debugger` and use the `Halt` and `Continue` buttons?

Answer (score 9):

I forwarded this question to Wolfram technical support and have received a reply. I quote the relevant part (slightly edited for clarity).

> The interruption of evaluation is intentionally removed [from the Evaluation menu in V10], but if you still would like to use it, you can use the keyboard combination: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>**.**</kbd>.
>
> ... filed a bug report for the [documentation] issue with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>**,**</kbd> with the development team.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, although the menu entry is gone in version 10 on Mac OS X, I just tried the keyboard shortcut and it seems to work:

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> brings up the kernel interrupt popup menu, as it did in previous versions.

Comment: thank you. I know this keyboard shortcut but it does not work for me.