# Suggestions for how to suspend a programme, while preserving the computations, which takes several days to finish?

Tags: export, dialog-window

I have a programme that needs to run for some time (2 days more or less). I only have access to a laptop, which I must turn off at the end of the day.

I thought of making my programme to export the computed data at the end of the day to a .txt file, and then on the next day to import it from the same file, and begin the computations from the last of the previous day.

For that, I thought of creating a main while cycle where we would define the variable 'stop', with a DialogInput box, so that the user could stop the programme at their desired time, without ruining the possible current computations.

For example:

```
stop=0;

While[stop==0 && numbComp<=UpBound,

    stop = DialogInput[
    DialogNotebook[{TextCell["Click to stop computations"], 
    Button["Stop", DialogReturn[1]]}]];

(*Heavy Computations Here*)

    numbComp++;

];
```

However, this method seems not to work since Mathematica will not proceed until the user has clicked a button in the dialogue box...

Addendum:

Well, after searching the wolfram documentation I wrote this:

```
stop = 0;
counter = 0;
CreateDialog[
  Column[{TextCell["Click to stop computations"], 
    Button["Stop", DialogReturn[stop = 1; Beep[] ]]}]];
While[stop == 0 && counter <= 5000000,

  data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 10], counter];(*This is just an example*)

  counter++;

  ];
```

This seems to work fine. If someone has a better idea, please share.

Comment: If you use Windows, you might hibernate it and resume the next day. This used to work many years ago. I no longer use windows so I do not know if it still does, and if problems would be expected.  For safety, you can also interrupt the computation first: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58446/12

Comment: @Szabolcs I've added some new information. I would like to know if you agree with it. Thanks for your comment. ;)